Relation between direct sum $\bigoplus$ and restricted product $\prod'$ of Galois cohomology
This is a question about the relation between directed sum $\bigoplus_{v \in M_K} H^1(\text{Gal}(\overline{K}/K), M)$
and restricted direct product $\prod'_{v \in M_K} H^1(\text{Gal}(\overline{K}/K), M)$.
Let me explain the definition of these two groups.
Let $K$ be a number field and $M$ be $G_K$ module. Let $M_K$ denote set of all places of $K$.
Take $v\in M_K$.
Let $K_v^{nr}$ denote the maximal unramified extension of $K_v$, and $I$ the corresponding subgroup of $\text{Gal}(\bar{K_v}/K_v)$. The image of inflation map $H^1(\text{Gal}(K_v^{nr}/K_v,M^I)\to H^1(\text{Gal}(\overline{K_v}/K_v), M)$ is called unramified cohomology $H^1_{nr}(\text{Gal}(\overline{K_v}/K_v),M)$.
Restricted direct product $\prod'_{v \in M_K} H^1(\text{Gal}(\overline{K_v}/K_v), M)$ is defined as set of tuples $(f_1,f_2,\cdots) \in \prod_{v\in M_K} H^1(\text{Gal}(\overline{K_v}/K_v), M)$ such that for all but finitely many $f_i$ lies in unramified cohomology $H^1_{nr}(\text{Gal}(\overline{K_v}/K_v),M)$.
On the other hand, direct sum $\bigoplus_{v \in M_K} H^1(\text{Gal}(\overline{K_v}/K_v), M)$  is defined as tuples $(f_1,f_2,\cdots) \in \prod_{v\in M_K} H^1(\text{Gal}(\overline{K_v}/K_v), M)$ such that for all but finitely many $f_i$ is $0$.
Clearly, $\bigoplus_{v \in M_K} H^1(\text{Gal}(\overline{K_v}/K_v), M)\subset \prod'_{v \in M_K} H^1(\text{Gal}(\overline{K_v}/K_v), M)$.
When does this two group coincides ?
To be precise, my question is,

in the case $M=E[2]$ where $E/K$ is an elliptic curve and
$E[2]=E(\overline{K})[2]$ is group of two torsion points.$\bigoplus_{v
 \in M_K} H^1(\text{Gal}(\overline{K_v}/K_v), M)=\prod'_{v \in M_K}
 H^1(\text{Gal}(\overline{K_v}/K_v), M)$  or does they have other
relation(for example there is surjection between them )?


Your definition of unramified cohomology needs to be fixed.

I suppose this is equivalent to the question "When do all but finitely many of the unramified cohomology groups vanish." Let $K$ be a local field and $I$ the inertia subgroup of its absolute Galois group. Inflation-restriction tells us the inflation map $H^1(K^{nr}/K,M^{I})\to H^1(\bar{K}/K,M)$ is injective, so we can equivalently ask when $H^1(K^{nr}/K,M^{I})$ vanishes. Another useful tool might be the fact that $\text{Gal}(K^{nr}/K)\simeq \hat{\mathbb{Z}}$.

Also, the definition of unramified cohomology in the question is incorrect. There is no inflation map from $H^1(\bar{K}/K^{nr},M)$ to $H^1(\bar{K}/K,M)$. That map would be corestriction. The correct map to consider is inflation from $H^1(K^{nr}/K,M^I)$ to $H^1(\bar{K}/K,M)$. I've edited the question to fix this.

I don't believe Prof. Bartel's answer is correct, in particular, I do not follow the implication [$M$ is unramified] $\Longrightarrow$ [the unramified cohomology of $M$ vanishes.]
Instead, I will make a claim contrary to the one posed in his answer. I believe the restricted product and direct sum are not isomorphic, and I will show this by demonstrating that infinitely many unramified cohomology groups are nonvanishing.
Proposition: Let $K$ be a global field and $M$ be a finite $G_K=\text{Gal}(\bar{K}/K)$ module with $|M|>1$. Then

infinitely many of the unramified cohomology groups $H^1_{nr}(K_{\mathfrak{p}},M)$ are nonvanishing.
let $L=K(M)$ be the smallest extension of $K$ such that $G_L$ acts trivially on $M$. Then the dirichlet density $\delta(S)$ of primes $\mathfrak{p}$ with $H^1_{nr}(K_{\mathfrak{p}},M)$ nontrivial is at least $1/[L:K]>0$.

Note that $(2)$ implies $(1)$, so we will prove the latter. Since $M$ is finite, $L/K$ is a finite extension and in particular only finitely many primes ramify in it. Since Dirichlet density is unaffected by finitely many primes, we will discard them in the following discussion. In the rest of the proof, every prime we consider is assumed to be unramified in $L/K$.
For a prime $\mathfrak{p}$, fix an embedding $\bar{K}\to \bar{K}_{\mathfrak{p}}$, this is equivalent to selecting a prime $\bar{\mathfrak{p}}$ lying over $\mathfrak{p}$ in $\bar{K}$. Let $I$ and $D$ be the inertia and decomposition groups of $\bar{\mathfrak{p}}$ respectively. By my comment, it suffices to determine which primes $\mathfrak{p}$ have $H^1(K_{\mathfrak p}^{nr}/K_{\mathfrak p},M^I)\neq 0$. By assumption, $\mathfrak{p}$ is unramified in $L$ and therefore $I\subseteq G_L$, so $M^I=M$, so we are computing $H^1(K_{\mathfrak p}^{nr}/K_{\mathfrak p},M)$. We will show that if $D\subseteq G_L$ (in other words, $\mathfrak{p}$ is completely split in $L$,) we have $H^1(K_{\mathfrak p}^{nr}/K_{\mathfrak p},M)\neq 0$. To do this, we will need the following lemma
Lemma: Let $M$ be a finite $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$-module. Then $|H^0(\hat{\mathbb{Z}},M)|=|H^1(\hat{\mathbb{Z}},M)|$.
We will put off the proof of this lemma until after we prove the proposition. Continuing the proof of the proposition, note that if $D\subseteq G_L$, we have that $D/I=\text{Gal}(K_{\mathfrak{p}}^{nr}/K_{\mathfrak{p}})$ acts trivially on $M$ because $D$ acts trivially on $M$, implying that $H^0(K_{\mathfrak{p}}^{nr}/K_{\mathfrak{p}},M)=M\neq 0$. Since $\text{Gal}(K_{\mathfrak{p}}^{nr}/K_{\mathfrak{p}})=\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$, the lemma applies and we get $|H^1(K_{\mathfrak{p}}^{nr}/K_{\mathfrak{p}},M)|=|H^0(K_{\mathfrak{p}}^{nr}/K_{\mathfrak{p}},M)|\neq 1$. The condition $D\subseteq G_L$ is equivalent to $\mathfrak{p}$ being completely split in $L$. By Tchebotarev density, this is satisfied for a set $S$ of primes of Dirichlet density $\delta(S)=1/[L:K]$.

We will now sketch a proof of the lemma. There is likely a more elementary proof than the one I am about to propose, but this is all I can think of at the moment. The goal will to develop a sort of duality theory for $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$-modules. All citations are to the book Cohomology of Number Fields by Neukirch, Schmidt, and Wingberg. Let $G=\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ for convinience. By the example after corollary 3.3.4, we have that the cohomological dimension of $G$ is $1$. For a $G$-module or abelian group $A$, define $A^*=\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(A,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$. Define the group
$$D^1(\hat{\mathbb{Z}}):=\varinjlim_{m}\varinjlim_{U\subseteq G} H^1(U,\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^*$$
where the inner direct limit is taken over the maps $\text{cor}^*$ dual to corestriction, and the outer is taken with respect to the maps induced by functoriality. By direct calculation, we find that $D_1(\hat{\mathbb{Z}})\simeq \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ as a $G$-module. We now satisfy the assumptions of theorem 3.4.4 and obtain an isomorphism
$$H^1(G,M)^*\simeq \text{Hom}_{G}(M,D^1(\hat{\mathbb{Z}}))\simeq \text{Hom}_{G}(M,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}).$$
We have $\text{Hom}_{G}(M,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})=(M^*)^G=H^0(G,M^*)$. This means we have
$$H^1(G,M)^*\simeq H^0(G,M^*).$$
Now, since dualizing preserves order, we have $|H^1(G,M)|=|H^1(G,M)^*|=|H^0(G,M^*)|$. But since $M^*$ is non-canonically isomorphic to $M$ with the opposite $G$-action, we obtain $|H^0(G,M^*)|=|H^0(G,M)|$. This proves the lemma.

I believe the bound in the proposition can be greatly improved on, but it would require a more careful analysis of the structure of $M$. In particular, the lemma reduced the question of whether an unramified cohomology group vanished to whether $M^D=0$. By using primes completely split in $L$, we showed that $M^D\neq 0$ by showing $M^D=M$. In general, far more primes could have $M^D\neq 0$.
Also, my proof assumed $|M|<\infty$. I suspect this result can be generalized to $M$ finitely generated as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module. However, in this case one needs a much more powerful version of the lemma. This is because the strict cohomological dimension of $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ is $2$, so the duality theory would become more complicated.

My answer was indeed non-sense and I deleted it.
